# How to write the results to output file (preferably excel) for each run

Tags: matlab, file-io, file-writing

I have a simple matlab code using transition matrix and doing monte carlo simulation. I have attached the code.

What I need you to do is: Write the results of each run in excel with the changing pattern size. The code just write the last numbers as usual. I would like to see each run results for an array called "pattern". For example "pattern" will be like this (Assuming that t=3 and;

```
Run1--- 45 12 17 17 17
Run2--- 56 24 24
Run3--- 7  45 45 21
```

In the matlab code below:
pattern: Visit pattern to company, say customer visited company 2 then company... , so the pattern 2-3...
Pr: Number of times company i visited
Seq: Number of times company sequential visits to company i
[Here is the transition matrix excel]

```
   clear all;
   clc;
   t=10;
      for ii=1:t
      .
      %(The codes created the pattern array)
      .
          filename=('output1.xlsx');
          xlswrite(filename,pattern,sheet1,'B2:NT2');

       end
```

When I use the code it gives me only the last result when ii=3;

```
         Run3--- 7  45 45 21
```

It does not have to be excel, other output file will be ok too.
I tried to use sprintf but it does not work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don't repost your questions if you don't get a sufficient answer. I suggest deleting [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687826/how-to-write-the-matlab-results-in-excel-that-has-different-runs).

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a string using [`sprintf`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

```
SheetRange = sprintf('B%i:NT%i',ii+1,ii+1);
xlswrite(filename,pattern,sheet1,SheetRange);
```

`sprintf` writes a string with the specified format, in this case `'B%i:NT%i'`, where the `%i` denotes an integer should go there. Since you specify `%i` twice, you need two integers to go into the string, hence the `ii+1,ii+1`.

And of course, as always: consider [not using `i` as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Comment: Hi Adriaan, Can you clarify for ii+1 part please?

Comment: Undefined function or variable 'ii'.

Error in monte9 (line 64)
       SheetRange = sprintf('B%i:NT%i',ii+1,ii+1);

Comment: @Dr.Turkuaz I used `ii` as a variable as opposed to `i`. See the link I posted on why I did that. Simply change your for loop to `for ii=1:t`

Comment: @Dr.Turkuaz there is an "edit" link for each of your questions. If you don't have an answer to a question, feel free to change it to your updated needs rather than asking a new question instead. And if you *do* ask a new question instead: delete the old one if it doesn't have any answers.

Comment: @Dr.Turkuaz thank you for the upvote, but it is not accepting. Accepting can be done by pressing the check mark below the voting arrows on the question.